# Responsive text on image

Tags: html, css

for couple of hours I'am trying to make responsive image with text that grow/shrink and finnaly made it... (Last time I have used html/css was 12 years ago) There is one thing that bother me, is it possible to increase width of the "textbox"?

- Green - actual size of div with text,
- Red - desired size of div for text to float

[image]

```html
<html>
   <link rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine">
   <link rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato">
   <head>
   </head>
   <div style="position: relative;
      display: inline-block;">
   <img style=" display: block;" src="http://wordpress1793681.home.pl/autoinstalator/wordpressplus2/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/contact2darker.jpg" alt="" width="512" height="215" />
   <div style=" position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate( -50%, -50% );
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      ">
   <p style="line-height: 1; margin-bottom: 0px;margin-top: 0px; font-size: 4.5vw; font-weight: 600;">CONTACT US LOREM IPSUM </p>
   <p style="line-height: 1; margin-bottom: 0px;margin-top: 0px; font-size: 3.75vw; font-weight: 300;">LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM </p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When I use the 'Run code snippet' button above, it looks like it already has the desired size... am I missing something?

Comment: No, I made mistake in text :) Its 4 am and I am still trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply put a `width` on the element containing the text.  (For clarity I pulled that one block of CSS into a classname instead of leaving it inline in the HTML; you should consider doing the same for the rest of your CSS, as it will make things much easier to maintain.)

```css
.textContainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate( -50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div style="position: relative;
      display: inline-block;">
  <img style=" display: block;" src="http://wordpress1793681.home.pl/autoinstalator/wordpressplus2/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/contact2darker.jpg" alt="" width="512" height="215" />
  <div class="textContainer">
    <p style="line-height: 1; margin-bottom: 0px;margin-top: 0px; font-size: 4.5vw; font-weight: 600;">CONTACT US LOREM IPSUM </p>
    <p style="line-height: 1; margin-bottom: 0px;margin-top: 0px; font-size: 3.75vw; font-weight: 300;">LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Than you,I have fixed on problem than not exists :)